# Select query but show the result from record number 3

Tags: mysql, sql

I have some simple query:

```
SELECT * FROM table
```

You all know the result:

```
|id|   foo   |    bar   |
-------------------------
|1 |   aaa   |    123   |
|2 |   bbb   |    234   |
|3 |   ccc   |    345   |
|4 |   ddd   |    456   |
```

but, what I want to do show from record number 3? I know I can do it with `SELECT * FROM table where id=3`, but I need to set the record I choose is in first rank, let say I choose `id=3` so the result as follow:

```
|id|   foo   |    bar   |
-------------------------
|3 |   ccc   |    345   |
|4 |   ddd   |    456   |
|1 |   aaa   |    123   |
|2 |   bbb   |    234   |
```

or

```
|id|   foo   |    bar   |
-------------------------
|3 |   ccc   |    345   |
|1 |   aaa   |    123   |
|2 |   bbb   |    234   |
|4 |   ddd   |    456   |
```

is this possible?

Comment: Can you define 'rank'? is it a column? calculated?

Comment: I'm sorry for my poor english, rank means i need to sort the query result starts from the id I choose. Please see my table result above. but Erwin Brandstetter has enlightened me :D Thanks to you all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way you get `id = 3` first:

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl
ORDER BY (id = 3) DESC
-- ,id
```

Order by `id` additionally if you want the rest ordered, too.

#### Explanation:

The expression evaluates to [boolean](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/numeric-type-overview.html). `FALSE` (= 0 in mysql) sorts before `TRUE` (= 1 in mysql), so we order descending.

It also automatically covers the case of `id` being `NULL`. I quote the [manual again here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/working-with-null.html):

> When doing an ORDER BY, NULL values are presented first if you do
> ORDER BY ... ASC and last if you do ORDER BY ... DESC.