# Select query but show the result from record number 3

Tags: mysql, sql

I've seen this question:
[Select query but show the result from record number 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8259772/select-query-but-show-the-result-from-record-number-3)

Table

```
|id|   foo   |    bar   |
-------------------------
|1 |   aaa   |    123   |
|2 |   bbb   |    234   |
|3 |   ccc   |    345   |
|4 |   ddd   |    456   |
```

based on the link above I use the query

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table 
ORDER BY (id = 3) DESC
```

and the result is

```
|id|   foo   |    bar   |
-------------------------
|3 |   ccc   |    345   |
|1 |   aaa   |    123   |
|2 |   bbb   |    234   |
|4 |   ddd   |    456   |
```

So my question is, is there any way to show the result starts from record number 3,then 4, then 1 and the last is record number 2? 
So the result can be shown as follow:

```
|id|   foo   |    bar   |
-------------------------
|3 |   ccc   |    345   |
|4 |   ddd   |    456   |
|1 |   aaa   |    123   |
|2 |   bbb   |    234   |
```

My example above is only a model, my goal is how to sort the result from the record I choose to the max record then cycling to the first record. If I choose record number 3 then the result is

```
3,4,5,...,max,1,2
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this would work:

```
ORDER BY (id = 3) OR (id = 4) DESC, id ASC
```

ETA: Based on your comment, it seems that what you really want is for 1 & 2 to display LAST.  That would look like this:

```
ORDER BY id <= 2, id
```

Comment: Yes, it works, but if you just only have 4 records just like the example. What if I have let say 20 records?

Comment: @sapu - well then it would show as 3,4,1,2,5,6,7,etc.  Is that not what you expected?  If not, what did you want it to display if there were more than 4 records?

Comment: My question is only a model. I expect, if the records more than 4 then the result shown as 3,4,5,...,max,1,2

Answer (score 1):

To force a specific order like that you need to use a `CASE`:

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN id = 3 THEN 1
              WHEN id = 4 THEN 2
              WHEN id = 1 then 3
              WHEN id = 2 then 4
              ELSE 5 END ASC
```

Comment: Alternative version:

`ORDER BY id = 3 DESC , id = 4 DESC , id = 1 DESC , id = 2 DESC, id ASC`

Answer (score 0):

This may not be perfectly ideal because it requires two queries, but it's completely specified and doesn't rely on using booleans for ordering:

```
(SELECT * 
 FROM Table 
 WHERE id >= 3
 ORDER BY id ASC)
UNION
(SELECT *
 FROM Table
 WHERE id < 3
 ORDER BY id ASC)
```