# PostgreSQL: order by column, with specific NON-NULL value LAST

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by

When I discovered `NULLS LAST`, I kinda hoped it could be generalised to 'X LAST' in a `CASE` statement in the `ORDER BY` portion of a query.

Not so, it would seem.

I'm trying to sort a table by two columns (easy), but get the output in a specific order (easy), with *one specific value of one column to appear last* (got it done... ugly).

Let's say that the columns are `zone` and `status` (don't blame me for naming a column `zone` - I didn't name them). `status` only takes 2 values ('U' and 'S'), whereas `zone` can take any of about 100 values.

One subset of `zone`'s values is (in pseudo-regexp) `IN[0-7]Z`, and those are first in the result. That's easy to do with a `CASE`.

`zone` can also take the value 'Future', which should appear LAST in the result.

In my typical kludgy-munge way, I have simply imposed a `CASE` value of 1000 as follows:

```
group by zone, status
order by (
 case when zone='IN1Z' then 1
      when zone='IN2Z' then 2
      when zone='IN3Z' then 3
        .
        . -- other IN[X]Z etc
        .
      when zone = 'Future' then 1000
      else 11 -- [number of defined cases +1]
      end), zone, status
```

This works, but it's obviously a kludge, and I wonder if there might be one-liner doing the same.
Is there a cleaner way to achieve the same result?

Comment: The usual suspects are missing: Postgres version and table definition (what you get with `\d tbl` in psql), which would show us exact data types and NOT NULL constraints.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Postgres allows [`boolean`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-boolean.html) values in the `ORDER BY` clause, so here is your `generalised 'X LAST'`:

```
ORDER BY (my_column = 'X')
```

The expression evaluates to `boolean`, resulting values sort this way:

```
FALSE (0)
TRUE (1)
NULL
```

Since we deal with non-null values, that's all we need. Here is your one-liner:

```
...
ORDER BY (zone = 'Future'), zone, status;
```

Related:

- [Sorting null values after all others, except special](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21891803/sorting-null-values-after-all-others-except-special/21892611#21892611)
- [Select query but show the result from record number 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8259772/select-query-but-show-the-result-from-record-number-3/8259857#8259857)
- [SQL two criteria from one group-by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15948905/sql-two-criteria-from-one-group-by/16026308#16026308)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar postgreSQL specifically, but I've worked with similar problems in MS SQL server. As far as I know, the only "nice" way to solve a problem like this is to create a separate table of zone values and assign each one a sort sequence.

For example, let's call the table ZoneSequence:

```
Zone   | Sequence
------ | --------
IN1Z   |        1
IN2Z   |        2
IN3Z   |        3
Future |     1000
```

And so on. Then you simply join ZoneSequence into your query, and sort by the Sequence column (make sure to add good indexes!).

The good thing about this method is that it's easy to maintain when new zone codes are created, as they likely will be.