# How to split query result by data which may be present or absent in the column?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by

My query result is as follows:

```
-------------------
| id  | c1 |  c2  |
-------------------
|  1  |  3 |  4   |
-------------------
|  2  |  4 |  3   |
-------------------
|  3  |  5 |  4   |
-------------------
```

I want `c2` with 3 be the first row (3 came from another query) like this:

```
-------------------
| id  | c1 |  c2  |
-------------------
|  2  |  4 |  3   |
-------------------
|  1  |  3 |  4   |
-------------------
|  3  |  5 |  4   |
-------------------
```

But other rows must also be.

Comment: How about some `order by c2`?

Comment: Yes, but i want to use 3, and don't know how...

Comment: What have you tried so far? When you say "But other rows must also be", can you be a little more explicit? It's not clear what you want aside from the `order by` clause that @bernie suggested.

Comment: I want to split the query result into two items: First must have 3 in c2, second must not have 3 in c2. The only way i see is to make select to the result where c2 = 3 and another select where c2 != 3, lately append two selections one another. But it may become time consuming...

Comment: `... order by case when c2 = 3 then 1 else 2 end`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just `ORDER BY` a boolean expression:

```
...
ORDER BY (c2 = 3) DESC NULLS LAST, id;
```

Related (with explanation):

- [PostgreSQL: order by column, with specific NON-NULL value LAST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32193339/postgresql-order-by-column-with-specific-non-null-value-last/32195624#32195624)
- [Sorting null values after all others, except special](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21891803/sorting-null-values-after-all-others-except-special/21892611#21892611)