# DELETE excess rows per group

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group, sql-delete

I have a Postgres table with these columns:

```
  id          int8
, user_id     varchar
, is_favorite boolean
, join_time   timestamptz
```

I want to delete some rows in this table with some **conditions**:

1. Keep a maximum of **10** rows for each `user_id`.
2. These **10** rows must contain each `user_id`'s rows with `is_favorite=true`
   (There can't be more than 5 rows with `is_favorite=true` per `user_id`.)
3. The rest of 10 rows must be the ones with the latest `join_time`.

I want to delete rows past the 10 per user_id in this table.

##### Example

```
id|user_id                             |is_favorite|join_time                    
------------------------------------+------------------------------------+-------
1 |655caab8-ce81-11ed-afa1-0242ac120002|true       |2023-03-04 15:16:40.000 +0300
2 |655caab8-ce81-11ed-afa1-0242ac120002|true       |2023-03-03 15:16:25.000 +0300
3 |655caab8-ce81-11ed-afa1-0242ac120002|true       |2023-03-02 15:16:40.000 +0300
4 |655caab8-ce81-11ed-afa1-0242ac120002|false      |2023-04-22 15:16:40.000 +0300
5 |655caab8-ce81-11ed-afa1-0242ac120002|false      |2023-03-23 15:16:25.000 +0300
6 |655caab8-ce81-11ed-afa1-0242ac120002|false      |2023-03-21 15:16:25.000 +0300
7 |655caab8-ce81-11ed-afa1-0242ac120002|false      |2023-03-20 15:16:40.000 +0300
8 |655caab8-ce81-11ed-afa1-0242ac120002|false      |2023-03-19 15:16:25.000 +0300
9 |655caab8-ce81-11ed-afa1-0242ac120002|false      |2023-03-18 15:16:40.000 +0300
10|655caab8-ce81-11ed-afa1-0242ac120002|false      |2023-03-17 15:16:25.000 +0300
11|655caab8-ce81-11ed-afa1-0242ac120002|false      |2023-03-16 15:16:40.000 +0300
12|655caab8-ce81-11ed-afa1-0242ac120002|false      |2023-03-15 15:16:25.000 +0300
13|655caab8-ce81-11ed-afa1-0242ac120002|false      |2023-03-14 15:16:40.000 +0300
14|655caab8-ce81-11ed-afa1-0242ac120002|false      |2023-03-14 15:16:39.000 +0300
15|81c126b6-ce81-11ed-afa1-0242ac120002|true       |2023-03-01 12:16:25.000 +0300
16|81c126b6-ce81-11ed-afa1-0242ac120002|true       |2023-03-01 11:16:25.000 +0300
17|81c126b6-ce81-11ed-afa1-0242ac120002|true       |2023-03-01 10:16:25.000 +0300
18|81c126b6-ce81-11ed-afa1-0242ac120002|true       |2023-03-01 09:16:25.000 +0300
19|81c126b6-ce81-11ed-afa1-0242ac120002|true       |2023-03-01 08:16:25.000 +0300
20|81c126b6-ce81-11ed-afa1-0242ac120002|false      |2023-03-01 07:16:25.000 +0300
21|81c126b6-ce81-11ed-afa1-0242ac120002|false      |2023-03-01 06:16:25.000 +0300
22|81c126b6-ce81-11ed-afa1-0242ac120002|false      |2023-03-01 05:16:25.000 +0300
23|81c126b6-ce81-11ed-afa1-0242ac120002|false      |2023-03-01 04:16:25.000 +0300
24|81c126b6-ce81-11ed-afa1-0242ac120002|false      |2023-03-01 03:16:25.000 +0300
25|81c126b6-ce81-11ed-afa1-0242ac120002|false      |2023-03-01 02:16:25.000 +0300
26|81c126b6-ce81-11ed-afa1-0242ac120002|false      |2023-03-01 01:16:25.000 +0300
```

For `user_id = 655caab8-ce81-11ed-afa1-0242ac120002` these IDs must be deleted: **11,12,13,14**

For `user_id = 81c126b6-ce81-11ed-afa1-0242ac120002` these IDs must be deleted **25,26**.

Comment: Do you expect to delete (many) more rows than you keep? In that case: are you at liberty to create a new table with surviving rows to replace the old? Always declare your version of Postgres, please. An actual, complete `CREATE TABLE` script, also showing constraints, is much more helpful than any free-hand description.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are processing the whole table, using a simple subquery with `row_number()` should be fastest:

```sql
DELETE FROM tbl t
USING (
   SELECT id, row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id
                                 ORDER BY is_favorite DESC, join_time DESC
                                 ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS rn
   FROM   tbl t
   ) del
WHERE  t.id = del.id
AND    del.rn > 10;
```

Adding `ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING` is optional, but should make it substantially faster (until Postgres 16 is released). See:

- [Efficient downsampling of a selected timeseries to equidistant samples](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/320943/3684)

Applying the right sort order, this skips the top 10 of most desirable rows per user and deletes the rest.

`true` sorts before `false` in descending order. See:

- [PostgreSQL: order by column, with specific NON-NULL value LAST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32193339/postgresql-order-by-column-with-specific-non-null-value-last/32195624#32195624)

If there can be `null` values, you need to do more. Like, first of all clarify your question.

Obviously, there would be race conditions with concurrent writes. If there can be concurrent write load, take a write lock on the table in the same transaction first ...

If that's going to delete the majority of rows, it may be cheaper to create a new table of survivors instead ...

There are other ways. Like:

- [Is there a way to SELECT n ON (like DISTINCT ON, but more than one of each)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/133418/3684)

Aside: use type `uuid` for your `user_id` column. Much better. See:

- [Would index lookup be noticeably faster with char vs varchar when all values are 36 chars](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/89433/3684)
- [What is the optimal data type for an MD5 field?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/115316/3684)

Comment: great, thanks for quick response @ErwinBrandstetter . This script will execute 8 times in about 5 minutes in this table by adding `del.user_id in (x, y, z)` to the script.Table contains about 200K rows. Could this cause a performance issue?(version:PostgreSQL 12.10)

Comment: @ee_engineer: For just 3 given `user_id`, a different query will be far more efficient.  You should have said so. Basically, just push the additional `WHERE` clause down into the subquery. Maybe start a new question with your exact case.

Comment: thanks, i have opened new topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75895419/delete-excess-rows-per-group-with-criteria

Answer (score 0):

You can use row_number() twice. first one used to remove records above rank 10, and second one will be used to remove any records `is_favorite=true` above rank 5.

```
with cte as (
  select *, row_number() over (partition by user_id order by is_favorite desc, join_time desc) as rn,
  (CASE WHEN is_favorite = 'true'
        THEN row_number() over (partition by user_id order by is_favorite desc)
        ELSE 0
  END) as fav_rn
  from mytable
)
delete from mytable
where id in (
  select id
  from cte
  where rn>10 or fav_rn > 5
)
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/bfvwoyDZ)