# DELETE excess rows per group with criteria

Tags: database, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group, sql-delete, postgresql-12

I have a Postgres table with these columns:

```
  id          int8
, user_id     varchar
, is_favorite boolean
, join_time   timestamptz
```

I want to delete some rows in this table with some conditions:

- Keep a maximum of 10 rows for each `user_id`.
- These 10 rows must contain each `user_id`'s rows with `is_favorite=true` (There can't be more than 5 rows with `is_favorite=true` per `user_id`.)
- The rest of 10 rows must be the ones with the latest `join_time`.

I want to delete rows past the 10 per `user_id` in this table with multiple `user_id` criteria.

There is a topic without `user_id` criteria, but related to performance issues, I opened a new topic. For whole table deletion, **see:**

- [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75882813/delete-excess-rows-per-group](https://stackoverflow.com)

The script will execute 8 times in about 5 minutes.Table contains about 200K rows and relationol with `users` table.(version:PostgreSQL 12.10)

**Example:**

```
id|user_id                             |is_favorite|join_time                    
------------------------------------+------------------------------------+-------
1 |655caab8-ce81-11ed-afa1-0242ac120002|true       |2023-03-04 15:16:40.000 +0300
2 |655caab8-ce81-11ed-afa1-0242ac120002|true       |2023-03-03 15:16:25.000 +0300
3 |655caab8-ce81-11ed-afa1-0242ac120002|true       |2023-03-02 15:16:40.000 +0300
4 |655caab8-ce81-11ed-afa1-0242ac120002|false      |2023-04-22 15:16:40.000 +0300
5 |655caab8-ce81-11ed-afa1-0242ac120002|false      |2023-03-23 15:16:25.000 +0300
6 |655caab8-ce81-11ed-afa1-0242ac120002|false      |2023-03-21 15:16:25.000 +0300
7 |655caab8-ce81-11ed-afa1-0242ac120002|false      |2023-03-20 15:16:40.000 +0300
8 |655caab8-ce81-11ed-afa1-0242ac120002|false      |2023-03-19 15:16:25.000 +0300
9 |655caab8-ce81-11ed-afa1-0242ac120002|false      |2023-03-18 15:16:40.000 +0300
10|655caab8-ce81-11ed-afa1-0242ac120002|false      |2023-03-17 15:16:25.000 +0300
11|655caab8-ce81-11ed-afa1-0242ac120002|false      |2023-03-16 15:16:40.000 +0300
12|655caab8-ce81-11ed-afa1-0242ac120002|false      |2023-03-15 15:16:25.000 +0300
13|655caab8-ce81-11ed-afa1-0242ac120002|false      |2023-03-14 15:16:40.000 +0300
14|655caab8-ce81-11ed-afa1-0242ac120002|false      |2023-03-14 15:16:39.000 +0300
15|81c126b6-ce81-11ed-afa1-0242ac120002|true       |2023-03-01 12:16:25.000 +0300
16|81c126b6-ce81-11ed-afa1-0242ac120002|true       |2023-03-01 11:16:25.000 +0300
17|81c126b6-ce81-11ed-afa1-0242ac120002|true       |2023-03-01 10:16:25.000 +0300
18|81c126b6-ce81-11ed-afa1-0242ac120002|true       |2023-03-01 09:16:25.000 +0300
19|81c126b6-ce81-11ed-afa1-0242ac120002|true       |2023-03-01 08:16:25.000 +0300
20|81c126b6-ce81-11ed-afa1-0242ac120002|false      |2023-03-01 07:16:25.000 +0300
21|81c126b6-ce81-11ed-afa1-0242ac120002|false      |2023-03-01 06:16:25.000 +0300
22|81c126b6-ce81-11ed-afa1-0242ac120002|false      |2023-03-01 05:16:25.000 +0300
23|81c126b6-ce81-11ed-afa1-0242ac120002|false      |2023-03-01 04:16:25.000 +0300
24|81c126b6-ce81-11ed-afa1-0242ac120002|false      |2023-03-01 03:16:25.000 +0300
25|81c126b6-ce81-11ed-afa1-0242ac120002|false      |2023-03-01 02:16:25.000 +0300
26|81c126b6-ce81-11ed-afa1-0242ac120002|false      |2023-03-01 01:16:25.000 +0300
27|91a005bc-cf89-11ed-afa1-0242ac120002|true       |2023-01-08 05:27:25.000 +0300
28|91a005bc-cf89-11ed-afa1-0242ac120002|true       |2023-02-09 07:32:25.000 +0300
29|91a005bc-cf89-11ed-afa1-0242ac120002|false      |2023-02-10 08:51:25.000 +0300
```

For `user_id in '655caab8-ce81-11ed-afa1-0242ac120002, 81c126b6-ce81-11ed-afa1-0242ac120002'`  these IDs must be deleted: **11,12,13,14,25,26**

What is the most efficient way of deal with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Applied to the whole table (all users), the query I suggested to your previous question is faster.
Applied to only **a few given users**, I suggest:

```
DELETE FROM tbl t
USING (
   SELECT id, row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id
                                 ORDER BY is_favorite DESC, join_time DESC
                                 ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS rn
   FROM   tbl t
   WHERE  user_id = ANY ({'655caab8-ce81-11ed-afa1-0242ac120002
                          ,81c126b6-ce81-11ed-afa1-0242ac120002}')
   ) del
WHERE  t.id = del.id
AND    del.rn > 10;
```

Filter early.
An index with leading `user_id` will help a lot. (You probably have one.)
An index with leading `id` should exist in any case.

Other considerations as detailed in my previous answer:

- [DELETE excess rows per group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75882813/delete-excess-rows-per-group/75882923#75882923)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CTE (Common Table Expression) to achieve this.

```
WITH ranked_rows AS (
  SELECT
    id,
    user_id,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
      PARTITION BY user_id
      ORDER BY is_favorite DESC, join_time DESC
    ) AS row_num
  FROM your_table_name
  WHERE user_id IN ('655caab8-ce81-11ed-afa1-0242ac120002', '81c126b6-ce81-11ed-afa1-0242ac120002')
)
DELETE FROM your_table_name
WHERE id IN (
  SELECT id FROM ranked_rows WHERE row_num > 10
);
```